# How can I modify the test task added by the android plugin?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Android provides a plugin that adds a test task. I can see this task if I do ./gradlew tasks. I can not see this task if I use `println tasks` to print out all the tasks in the tasks object.

If I try to configure the `test` task with a closure like this `test {}` then I get an error that says,

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':android'.
> Could not find method test() for arguments [build_bscqz3ourvdryhsbx87icqw6s$_run_closure5@3765c654] on project ':android'.
```

but which is just bizarre to me. I don't understand why the task isn't already available, since I've processed the plugin code with the plugin import statement already.

`println tasks` output

```
[task ':android:assemble', task ':android:assembleDebug', task ':android:assembleDev', task ':android:assembleProd', task ':android:assembleRelease', task ':android:blah', task ':android:build', task ':android:buildDependents', task ':android:buildNeeded', task ':android:check', task ':android:clean', task ':android:connectedCheck', task ':android:deviceCheck', task ':android:preBuild', task ':android:uninstallAll']
```

./gradlew tasks output

```
lintDevRelease - Runs lint on the DevRelease build.
lintProdDebug - Runs lint on the ProdDebug build.
lintProdRelease - Runs lint on the ProdRelease build.
test - Run unit tests for all variants.
testDevDebug - Run unit tests for the devDebug build.
testDevRelease - Run unit tests for the devRelease build.
testProdDebug - Run unit tests for the prodDebug build.
testProdRelease - Run unit tests for the prodRelease build.
```

gradle.build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 0
def versionMinor = 1
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 1 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.apply plugin: 'android'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
def buildTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

android {
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22

        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.multidex.MultiDexTestRunner"

        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
    }

    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
            versionNameSuffix '-dev'
        }

        release {

        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.0.1'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.9'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid-framework:0.24.0'

    compile 'com.github.matthewyork:ColoursLibrary:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.7'

    compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick:2.3.6'
    provided 'com.github.frankiesardo:icepick-processor:2.3.6'

    compile 'nl.qbusict:cupboard:2.1.1'

    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}

test {
    dependsOn ':server:integrationTomcatRun'
}


//task.test.dependsOn ':server:integrationTomcatRun'
println this
task blah {
    println tasks
    println tasks[1].name
    println tasks.findByName("test")
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    include '**/integration/*.*'
    println integrationTest
    testClassesDir = file('build/intermediates/classes')
//    if (System.getenv("WEBSITE_BASE_URL") != null && System.getenv("WEBSITE_BASE_URL").contains("localhost:8090")) {
//        dependsOn ':server:integrationTomcatRun'
//        finalizedBy ':server:integrationTomcatStop'
//    }
//    testLogging {
//        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
//    }
}
```

gradlew tasks --all

Had to move this to pastebin, too big for the normal question window. http://pastebin.com/i6DdHwXB

Comment: Could you try printing the output of `gradle tasks --all`?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek Added it to the bottom with a pastebin link.

Comment: And what exact command do you run when you get that error?

Comment: ./gradlew tasks --all

Comment: You get `A problem occurred evaluating project ':android'.
> Could not find method test() for arguments [build_bscqz3ourvdryhsbx87icqw6s$_run_closure5@3765c654] on project ':android'.` when you run `gradle tasks --all`?

Comment: If I have a test {} closure defined I get that error when gradle tries to process the android project's build.gradle for the first time (gradle goes over all the build.gradle files one time to set everything up before executing real tasks). It doesn't matter what command I run. ./gradlew tasks fails just the same as ./gradlew test or anything else.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry - I have voted your question down by mistake. Can you edit it slightly, i.e. by adding some more data, so I will vote it back up.

Comment: You could try putting the test closure with your modification in a `configure(project(...))` section. See if this helps.